# временные коды на php

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно сделать возможность добавлять записи в таблицу mysql а через какой-то промежуток времени(например 1 день, время можно задать самому) автоматически удалить его из таблицы? используя php

Comment: Создайте колонку в которой будет время действия строки. перед запросом сделайте еще один запрос который удаляет те записи, у которых истекло время

Comment: *используя php* Зачем? Для этого у MySQL есть свой, родной Event Scheduler. Создал запись - и забыл, шедулер её по истечении времени жизни сам удалит.

Answer (score 0):

Если именно на PHP.

Предложил бы добавить колонку **время жизни записи**.

В переменную время создания записывать текущий time().

```
$current_time = time();
```

Затем записывать переменную с указанием жизни сессии.

```
$alive_time = $current_time + 60*60*24 //добавляем сутки (time() в секундах)
```

Записываем переменную в базу данных при создании записи.

Затем пишем проверку.
В переменную $alive_time достаём переменную из БД нужной записи и проверяем.

```
if($current_time > $alive_time) {
//удаляем запись
}
```

Проблема в том, что код будет удалять записи, только когда переходят на страницу, где он расположен, поэтому лучше оформить всё через cron. Ссылка: [Информация](https://ru.hostings.info/schools/cron.html#2)

Answer (score 0):

Вам в базе нужно хранить время создания записи. При выборке добавляете условие `время создания + время жизни >= текущему времени` (чтобы записи с истекшим временем не попадали в выборку), плюс по расписанию запускайте скрипт, который будет удалять протухшие записи.

Если время жизни для записей в одной таблице может быть разным, то добавьте колонку с временем протухания, записывайте туда нужное время при добавлении и при выборке/удалении ориентируйтесь на него.